# Efficiently Row Standardize a Matrix

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, scipy

I need an efficient way to row standardize a sparse matrix.

Given

```
W = matrix([[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]])
row_sums = W.sum(1)
```

I need to produce...

```
W2 = matrix([[0.  , 0.5 , 0.  , 0.5 , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
             [0.33, 0.  , 0.33, 0.  , 0.33, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
             [0.  , 0.5 , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.5 , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
             [0.33, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.33, 0.  , 0.33, 0.  , 0.  ],
             [0.  , 0.25, 0.  , 0.25, 0.  , 0.25, 0.  , 0.25, 0.  ],
             [0.  , 0.  , 0.33, 0.  , 0.33, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.33],
             [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.5 , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.5 , 0.  ],
             [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.33, 0.  , 0.33, 0.  , 0.33],
             [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.5 , 0.  , 0.5 , 0.  ]])
```

Where,

```
for i in range(9):
    W2[i] = W[i]/row_sums[i]
```

I'd like to find a way to do this without loops (i.e. Vectorized) and using Scipy.sparse matrices. W could be as large at 10mil x 10mil.

Comment: I just realized if W is dense (a regular numpy matrix). W2 = W/W.sum(1) works fine.  But scipy's sparse matrices don't appear to support division.

Comment: I don't see a way of doing that other than implementing this division in C code and calling from Python. Does the W.sum for sparse matrix works ok?

Comment: Yes, W.sum(1) on the sparse returns a vector of row sums.

Comment: The values of W2 are always (1./row_sum). Maybe there is an easy way to replace the 1's in W with values from a column vector?

Comment: Here's a simple way to do this with sklearn: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305021/efficient-way-to-normalize-a-scipy-sparse-matrix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

with a bit of matrix algebra

```
>>> cc
<9x9 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 24 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
>>> ccd = sparse.spdiags(1./cc.sum(1).T, 0, *cc.shape)
>>> ccn = ccd * cc
>>> np.round(ccn.todense(), 2)
array([[ 0.  ,  0.5 ,  0.  ,  0.5 ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.33,  0.  ,  0.33,  0.  ,  0.33,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.5 ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.5 ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.33,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.33,  0.  ,  0.33,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.25,  0.  ,  0.25,  0.  ,  0.25,  0.  ,  0.25,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.33,  0.  ,  0.33,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.33],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.5 ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.5 ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.33,  0.  ,  0.33,  0.  ,  0.33],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.5 ,  0.  ,  0.5 ,  0.  ]])
>>> ccn
<9x9 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 24 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```