# Memory-efficient normalization of scipy sparse arrays

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, normalization, sparse-matrix

I have a script that reads in a corpus of many short documents and vectorizes them using `sklearn`. The result is a large, sparse matrix (specifically, a `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix`) with dimensions 371k x 100k. My goal is to normalize this such that each row sums to 1, i.e. divide each entry by the sum of the entries in its row. I've tried several ways of doing this and each has given me a `MemoryError`:

- `M /= M.sum(axis=1)`
- `M_normalized = sklearn.preprocessing.normalize(M, axis=1, norm='l1')`
- a for loop which sums and divides the rows one at a time and adds the result to an all-zero matrix

For the first option, I used `pdb` to stop the script right before the normalization step so I could monitor memory consumption with htop. Interestingly, as soon as I stepped forward in the script to execute `M /= M.sum(axis=1)`, the memory error was thrown immediately, in under a second.

My machine has 16GB of memory + 16GB swap, but only around 8GB + 16GB free at the point in the program where the normalization takes place.

Can anyone explain why all these methods are running into memory problems? Surely the third one at least should only use a small amount of memory, since it's only looking at one row at a time. Is there a more memory-efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: the 3rd way (in a loop) should work if you don't save the result to a new matrix but you divide the line of the same matrix (`M[i] /= M[i].sum()`). This will save you from creating a second matrix of the same size and therefore save memory.

Comment: How many nonzero values are in the matrix?

Comment: This is a large sparse matrix; so the usual `numpy` array ideas don't apply.  For one thing, `M.sum(axis=1)` is performed with a matrix multiplication.  Row indexing `M[i,:]` is also much slower.  And for multiple rows is actually performed with a matrix multiplication (as discussed in another recent `sparse` question).

Comment: Shot in the dark (I haven't tried it): Use `sklearn.preprocessing.normalize(M, axis=1, norm='l1', copy=False)` to normalize `M` in-place.

Comment: `sklearn` uses compiled `cython` code in `https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/utils/sparsefuncs_fast.pyx` to perform the `inplace_csr_row_normalize_l1`.  It looks a lot like what I'd do if doing the normalization inplace using the matrix `indptr`, `indicies` and `data` attributes.

Comment: @hpaulj Great.  Does it work with nomarch's matrix?  I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: @nomarch: See the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358962/efficiently-row-standardize-a-matrix

Comment: I tried `sklearn.preprocessing.normalize(M, axis=1, norm='l1', copy=False)` with a sparse CSR matrix of size (371000, 100000) and 18550000 nonzero elements, and it worked fine.

Comment: If making a copy during this normalization step causes a memory error, what will the rest of the `sklearn` processing do?  I just answered a question about splitting a sparse matrix into training and testing matrices.

Comment: @Warren Weckesser My matrix has just under 21M nonzero entries, or about 0.056% of the total. Normalizing in-place with `sklearn.preprocessing.normalize(M, axis=1, norm='l1', copy=False)` appears to have done the trick.